# Rank-size log-log plot inflection: drooping tail of power law

Tags: power-law

Most of my data seems nicely to fit a power law but with a "drooping tail", which I believe is quite common, although in this case the drop-off is quite steep.
[image]

I have two related questions if I may combine them in this post:

1. How to locate this inflection precisely and justifiably
   (mathematically) in the data?
2. Is it possible to justify separate statistical treatment of each side of the inflection, e.g. power law for the top and what else for the bottom? Since this kind of drop-off seems common, is there a common explanation for them which might justify separate treatment? NB: This is a distribution of firm birthrates across cities. The associated literature mentions that it is common just to cut off the drooping tail when fitting a power law, but it seems unrigorous to do so.

Comment: How is "firm birthrate" calculated?

Comment: @Glen_b A ratio of yearly firm births over number of establishments, by city. In this graph, birthrates are averaged over 20 years.

Comment: I wonder if the kink is a consequence of some of the counts getting close to 0 and the averaging step.

Comment: @Glen_b Absolutely. The median of the panel data is 0.24 but the max is 19.6.